# Spring boot maven plugin and antlr4-runtime issue

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, maven, antlr4

When I run my application, below exception is being thrown while initialization.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/antlr/v4/runtime/misc/ParseCancellationException
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryEngineImpl.resolveHqlTranslator(QueryEngineImpl.java:155) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryEngineImpl.from(QueryEngineImpl.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:285) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:450) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1507) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:388) ~[spring-orm-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:364) ~[spring-orm-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1833) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.ParseCancellationException
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[?:?]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryEngineImpl.resolveHqlTranslator(QueryEngineImpl.java:155) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryEngineImpl.from(QueryEngineImpl.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:285) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
```

On checking it was found that spring-boot-maven-plugin transitively adds antlr4-runtime- 4.7.2, which overrides the antlr4-runtime-4.13.0 from spring-data. I tried excluding antlr dependency from spring-boot-maven-plugin, but exclusion is not working.

```
    <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>repackage</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>
                                <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
                                <artifactId>antlr4-runtime</artifactId>
                            </exclude>
                        </excludes>
                        <classifier>exec</classifier>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
<plugin>
```

.......

```
 <profile>
            <id>IT</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>repackage</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>
                                    <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>antlr4-runtime</artifactId>
                                </exclude>
                            </excludes>
                            <classifier>exec</classifier>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
```